# Cannot Connect to local HTTP Servers - Synology

Tags: network, wifi, nas

I have a network including multiple machines - PCs, Android, iOS, Mac devices and a Synology. My mac is running Catalina 10.15.4.

Everything connects to the Synology fine except the Mac over `http` or `https`.

I have connected Finder to the Synology shared drives using `afp://<servername>.local`.

All my other devices connect to any Synology hosted web sites fine using this address:

```
https://<servername>:port
```

Using this on the Mac just times out. However if I add the `local` suffix, or I use the IP address, it works:

```
https://<servername>.local:port
https://<ipaddress>:port
```

It pops up the self-signed cert warning (for the Synology cert) and then proceeds to the web site hosted on the Synology, such as GitLab or DSM Control Panel.

But seeing that I have all manner of scripts and repositories of code I can't just have one machine throwing such a curve ball into my configuration. It seems many people have had issues with Catalina networking from reading [this thread](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/129160) on the Synology forums. The problems and solutions described there are primarily about Finder connections, which work fine for me.

From all my reading online it seems the solution everyone quotes is to add search domains.

So I added `local` as a search domain to my Wi-Fi adapters Preferences -> Network -> Wi-Fi -> Advanced -> DNS tab. Rebooted (several times now) and I still cannot get the Mac to browse to the sites. I've also tried `.local`.

Nothing seems to work.

I've also checked and confirmed that my mac is using the same DNS server as my PC and all that checks out fine too.

I've no active proxies. Also there is a `*.local` listed in the proxy bypass settings but that seems a reasonable setting. I've tried removing it and rebooting anyway but that didn't help.

**nslookup servername**

```
Server: 194.168.4.100
Address:194.168.4.100#53

Non-Authoritative answer:
Name: <servername>
Address: 92.242.132.24
```

**dig servername**

This seems to return a sensible response as it gets an answer from the server.

What other settings or configuration might help?

Comment: `.local` has many documented issues especially when dealing with 3rd party products like a NAS (and especially so for Microsoft stuff).  Have your DHCP server config everything to use a `.lan` or a TLD not in use.  You can search [ICANN's official list](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en).  I use `.home` personally for my home network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to another local domain, such as `.lan`, instead of the reserved [`.local`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local). Bonjour/ZeroConf [reserves the use](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202887/mac-doesnt-use-local-dns-for-local?rq=1) of `.local`. If you are using DHCP, your server can handle this configuration.

Alternatively, [hardcode the server's IP address](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164015/adding-local-to-the-dns-search-domains-has-no-effect) in `/etc/hosts` with the line:

```
a.x.y.z      <servername>
```